# What is the real benefit of arrow functions although when they lack - this, arguments, new, super?

Tags: javascript

Arrow functions:

Do not have `this`.
Do not have `arguments`.
Can’t be called with `new`.

(They also don’t have super, but we didn’t study it. Will be in the chapter Class inheritance, super).

Comment: They described lot I want very simple points. Not the difference but benefits.

Comment: Some of the differences can be benefits, in specific situations.